# Does data get lost due to backpressure?

Tags: node.js

In the following code, when `write.write(chunk)` (LINE A) returns `false`, it means chunk has not been written in destination `buffer` as its full. Yes I have paused after writing failure, but it has already been emitted from `read` stream and can't be written on the write strea,. Where does that perticular chunk go? Does it get lost? Or does it somehow gets  restored?

```
// create polyfill of pipe named **pipe1**

const {createReadStream, createWriteStream} = require('fs');
const path = require('path')

const videoPath = path.join(__dirname, 'video.mp4')
const copyPath = path.join(__dirname, 'video1.mp4')

const read = createReadStream(videoPath)
const write = createWriteStream(copyPath)

function pipe1(writeStream){
    this.on('data', function(chunk){
        const success = write.write(chunk) // LINE A
        if(!success){
            console.log("failed because of backpressure. could not write chunk1", chunk)
        }
        this.pause();
    })

    writeStream.on('drain', () => {
            this.resume();
        });
}

Object.getPrototypeOf(read).pipe1 = pipe1;
read.pipe1(write)
```